# OpenCV - append part of image

Tags: python, opencv

I have a scanned document image of some black text on a white background. I first invert the image so background = black and all text = white.

I then use OpenCV's `reduce()` function to give me a vertical projection on the image, which looks a little like: *(sum of all pixel values for each row in the image)*

```
0,
0,
0,
434
34
0,
0,
```

From this, I can tell that 0 pixel values denote the background whereas values > 0 depict there is some text.

From here, I've looped through the pixel values looking for any 0 values in which the next value != 0 (The next value is contains text) and stored the positions in a two tuple list namely `pairedCoordinates`: `[(23, 43), (54, 554)]` etc...

From that point I can then loop through `pairedCoordinates` and draw `boundingRects` around my regions of interest:

```
for start, finish in pairedCoordinates:
    height = finish - start
    cv2.rectangle(small, (0, start), (0+cols, start + height), (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

Up to this point, all works fine. What I'm trying to do next, is for each rectangle, append its inner content (pixels) to another list so I can perform further computations on only sections of the image contained within the rects.

I've attempted the following:

```
# Initialise an empty list 
roi = []
```

and then within the above for loop, I add the additional:

```
for start, finish in pairedCoordinates:
    height = finish - start
    cv2.rectangle(small, (0, start), (0+cols, start + height), (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # cols = the number of columns in the image, small being the image
    glyph = small[y: start + height, x:0+cols] 
    roi.append(glyph)
```

When attempting this code, I'm getting 'Unresolved references to x & y and I'm a little unsure why.

Could someone just point me in the right direction of how to actually achieve what I've explained above.

**UPDATE**
As mentioned by Miki in the comments, I forgot to initialise x, y.
I simply defined `x=0 y=0` before computing the glyph and that seemed to do the trick.

I'm having some issues looping through each of the areas and writing them to a file though. Instead of each bounding rect being written individually, each new image file created is just appending the next pixels to the existing image?

```
for i, r in enumerate(roi):
    cv2.imwrite("roi_%02d.png" % i, r)
```

Comment: x and y are not defined/initialized anywhere

Comment: I tried adding: `x, y, w, h = small` but i'm getting a ValueError: to many values to unpack

Comment: `x` and `y` might be the coordinates of the rectangle he mentioned @Miki

Comment: @Jeru yeah I got that... but he never finds a rectangle and never declares x,y. He just uses `0` and `cols` as the x coordinate. He only has "y" coordinates of the rectangle through `start` and `finish`, but he never actually declares a variable `y`

Comment: Thanks @Miki, you were right xD

Comment: I've just updated my question with a small issue if you could take a look @Miki

Comment: You don't want to set y to `0`, but to `start`

Comment: Oh yeah, that solved it all, thanks for your help :)

Comment: I'll have to look into it. Thanks again